# How to reverse Geocode in google maps api 2 android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to do reverse geocoding in my app using map api 2.But i dont know exactly how to do that?Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html):

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context);
List<Address> matches = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
Address bestMatch = (matches.isEmpty() ? null : matches.get(0));
```

Comment: i have done this for geocoding and it works.My problem is that i want to do reverse geocoding.From a point of map get the address.But thanks anyway!

Comment: GeoCoder does reverse geocoding as well - I've updated my code to use getFromLocation, which takes in a latitude and longitude and reverse geocodes that into an address.

Comment: @ianhanniballake is correct, you will need to use the `GeoCoder`. Just to add an additional comment I formatted my address as such: `String addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                 bestMatch.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? bestMatch.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                 bestMatch.getLocality(),
                 bestMatch.getCountryName());`. This allows me to display the street address to the user just by simply passing the `addressText` value via toast.

Comment: Are there any limits on reverse geocoding calls? I am directly invoking the http api like: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=n,m - is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: Both the Android API and the http API are IP address limited in number of requests AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works for me..

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions;

 Location myLocation;
 Button btLocInfo;

String selectedLocAddress;
     private GoogleMap myMap;
LatLng latLng;
 LatLng tmpLatLng;
    @Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

    // Getting the Latitude and Longitude of the touched location
    latLng = point;
    // Clears the previously touched position
    myMap.clear();
    // Animating to the touched position
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    // Creating a marker
    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    // Setting the position for the marker
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    // Adding Marker on the touched location with address

    new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng);
    //tmpLatLng = latLng;

    btLocInfo.setEnabled(true);


    btLocInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            double[] coordinates={tmpLatLng.latitude/1E6,tmpLatLng.longitude/1E6};

            double latitude = tmpLatLng.latitude;
            double longitude = tmpLatLng.longitude;

            Log.i("selectedCoordinates", latitude + " " + longitude);
            Log.i("selectedLocAddress", selectedLocAddress);


        }
    });
}


private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String>{
    Context mContext;
    public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context){
        super();
        mContext = context;
        }
    // Finding address using reverse geocoding
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
        double latitude = params[0].latitude;
        double longitude = params[0].longitude;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        String addressText="";
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
            Thread.sleep(500);


        if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 ){
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                            address.getLocality(),
                            address.getCountryName());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        selectedLocAddress = addressText;
        return addressText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {
        // Setting the title for the marker.
        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
        markerOptions.title(addressText);
        // Placing a marker on the touched position
        myMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this to get complete address :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     ...

private Geocoder geocoder;
private TextView mAddressTxtVu;

     ...


// assume that you got latitude and longitude correctly 

mLatitude  =  20.23232
mLongitude =  32.999

String errorMessage = "";

geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses = null;

try {
          addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                   mlattitude,
                   mlongitude,
                   1);
  } catch (IOException e) {
          errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
          Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, e);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
                    // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
          errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
          Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " + "Latitude = " + mlattitude +", 
  Longitude = " + mlongitude, illegalArgumentException);
  }

  // Handle case where no address was found.
  if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
         if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                  errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                  Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
         }

  } else {
         Address address = addresses.get(0);
         ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

         // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
         // join them, and send them to the thread.
         for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                  addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
         }
         // Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.address_found));


  mAddressTxtVu.setText(TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                            addressFragments));
                }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Google Maps Api for this purpose. Android SKD have a class for it which you can simply use without any registration of API Key and so on. The class is `android.location.Geocoder`. It have methods for geocoding and reverse geocoding. I was looking in the source code of this class and found that it have a method `android.location.Geocoder#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String, int)` where first argument is address, and second is max number of results you want. It returns a `List<Address>`. The `Address` class have methods like `android.location.Address#getLatitude` and `android.location.Address#getLongitude`. They both return `double`.

Try it and let me know how good it is :-)