# Google map API return place name at any point

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want use google map to find out where i am at any instance. For i want to use google map API. The exact thing that i want that i give coordinates of some location and google tell me that what place exit on that particular coordinate, means name of the place. No matter whatever the place is. where cafe hospital or anything.

Comment: Check out this :http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191037/how-to-reverse-geocode-in-google-maps-api-2-android