# Can I use my Android API key when making http request to Google Map API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3

I have created an API key for my Android app like this in the Google Cloud Platform console

[image]

and then I use that Android API key to make request to Google Map API (reverse geocoding) to this endpoint below using HTTP client like retrofit or Dio (directly from my Android client app)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyCxxxxxxxxxxxddgaQTwwlYDBmP8&latlng=-6.150934,106.8251672
```

but unfortunately I get error json response from Google:

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API
> key. Request received from IP address 180.111.11.111, with empty
> referer

Can I use my Android API key when making http request from my Android client App to Google Map API? what should I do to make request to Google Map API from my Android client app? should I make my own endpoint as a 'wrapper' instead?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution plz?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use my Android API key when making http request from my Android client App to Google Map API?

No. Instead of using two keys, you should make a call through the SDK, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191083/3145360).

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context);
List<Address> matches = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
Address bestMatch = (matches.isEmpty() ? null : matches.get(0));
```